# Extbase: testing function with injected repository

Tags: phpunit, typo3, extbase

I use TYPO3 6.1.

I actually try to test a method with phpunit which uses a injected repository.

```
$mock = $this->getMockedRepository(
    '\\MyExt\\Domain\\Repository\\MyRepository',
    array(
        'findByUid' => array('count' => 0, 'return' => array()),
    )
);
$this->tokenHelperObj->injectMyRepository($mock);
```

The function *getMockedRepository* is just a helper that calls the *getMock*-function from *phpunit*. In other context this function works. In my helper-class i just use dependency injection like

```
/**
 * myRepository
 *
 * @var \MyExt\Domain\Repository\MyRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $myRepository;
```

When i call the test, i get

```
Call to undefined method Class::injectActivityRepository()
```

I dont want to write all inject-methods for the different repositories i use. Is there any other way to mock the injected repositories?

Comment: What is `$this->tokenHelperObj` and how do you get the repositories in there in your extension code (not the tests)?

Comment: `$this->tokenHelperObj` is my fixture-class which is initialized at the setUp and i want to test. I inject my repository like written in the question with `@inject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since TYPO3 6.1 the class \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase has been extended with the new method called inject(). This method can be used to inject dependiencies, so you don't have to create inject-methods.

Usage:

```
$this->inject($target, $name, $dependency)
```

Below follows an example test:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function serviceReturnsFalseIfNoRecordsFoundTest() {
    $mockQuery = $this->getMock('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface');

    $mockRepository = $this->getMock('\TYPO3\MyExtension\Domain\Repository\TestRepository');
    $mockRepository->expects($this->once())->method('findAll')->will($this->returnValue($mockQuery));

    $this->inject($this->fixture, 'testRepository', $mockRepository);

    $this->assertTrue($this->fixture->doSomething());
}
```

Comment: hi, the method $this->inject($target, $name, $dependency) is in \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Tests\Unit\BaseTestCase. Not in "\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase" !

Comment: `$this->fixture` is the main instance of the class you are unit testing. Usually you create it in the `setup()` of your test class. See https://github.com/derhansen/sf_event_mgt/blob/master/Tests/Unit/Service/ExportServiceTest.php for an example (note, my variable is called `$subject` instead of `$fixture`)